# cxShellTreeView component get the path

Tags: delphi, devexpress

i'm trying to get full path of the selected Folder. 
Only thing i was able to find is this
cxShellTreeView2.Folders[Index].PathName, but i don't know how to get this Index.

Comment: Did you ask devExpress?

Comment: yes, and i don't have an answer.

Comment: That's odd. I was under the impression that devExpress support was of a high standard? How long have you given them to answer?

Comment: It generally requires 24 hours or more to receive an answer to a devExpress forum question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it the path of the map?

```
self.cxShellTreeView2.Path;
```

or

```
self.cxShellTreeView2.AbsolutePath;
```

Description TcxCustomShellTreeView.AbsolutePath

Use the AbsolutePath property to specify the path to the required shell node. Folder path can be specified in two ways:

as a full path, including all sequence of folders, required for accessing the required shell node from the shell root.

Description TcxCustomShellTreeView.Path

Use the Path property to specify the path to the current shell item. Folder path can be specified in two ways:

as a full path, including all sequence of folders, required for accessing the required shell item from the shell root.

Comment: Yes Very Good! Works Fine :)

Answer (score 0):

The full path of a selected folder is returned by cxShellTreeView1.AbsolutePath.